# Testing Android and iOS with a flutter embedded parts

Tags: android, ios, flutter, testing, e2e-testing

What's the best way to test the following scenario?

1. Open native android app
2. Go to screen B written in flutter - click on button "OK"
3. Go to screen C which is a pure Android view again

Currently I use Appium but I can not find specific elements of B's screen because labels of button are not always available in inspector. In order to select button in tests i have to specify X and Y coordinates to push a click. I'm looking for a robust solution which will cover automated integration e2e test both for Android, iOS and flutter. Separate Flutter parts are tested in standalone mode using flutter integration test.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Flutter in most of cases build an app with `accessibility id` visible in Appium. This `accessibility id` is derived from Widget text and other UI elements. Unfortunately I couldn't find any `accessibility id` for Icon widget. In order to to find such Widget in Appium you have to wrap it in flutter with `Semantics` widget.

```
   Semantics(
          label: "EDIT_PROFILE",
          child: Icon(
```

After it's done you can easily find any widget in Appium.Answering main question: Appium is a good solution to test such scenarios where Flutter is only a embedded screen in Android app. I hope that test will go smoothly on iOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional info, I have developed a simple flutter app from `new flutter project` and add `accessibility id` to two widgets.

- sample for widget that already have `semanticsLabel`:

  ```
        Text(
          '$_counter',
          semanticsLabel: 'counterText$_counter',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
        ),
  ```
- sample for widget that does not have `semanticsLabel`, so we need to wrap it with `Semantics` widget:

  ```
   floatingActionButton: Semantics(
     label: 'incrementButton',
     child: FloatingActionButton(
       onPressed: _incrementCounter,
       tooltip: 'Increment',
       child: const Icon(Icons.add),
     ),
   ),
  ```

And then test it using Appium for both Android and iOS.
Please refer to this [link for the codes](https://github.com/imudita/appium_flutter/tree/main/e2e).